# testing of android apps via web

Tags: android

What tools allow *manual testing* of android apps (apks) without installing google android emulator, and with **low latency** (where low is defined as no more than 4x slower than google emulator)? The latency seems to be the hard part to solve for. We tried two services, neither great, and its time consuming to try out a new service with all the device emulators we need to use. Hope some of you can save me a bunch of time!

background:
App is stable, no problems on lots of physical devices or google emulator.
Data is coming from a service in AWS with consistent latency.
Tried browserstack, works okay, but its expensive.
Tried LambdaTest, had lots of app crashes, severe latency (1 minute for actions that take 2 seconds in emulator), rendering problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

QA teams performing software functional testing for mobile apps want to test the app on real/virtual devices. Multiple device ownership is challenging. Hence, cloud-based platforms provide software testing solutions to meet testing needs.

Browserstack is indeed expensive but allows us to test the iOS, Android, and browser efficiently (sometimes it gets pretty slow).

When I was researching the cloud-based platforms for mobile app testing, I identified a few additional platforms.

- AWS Device Farm
- Sauce Labs
- Firebase Test Lab for Android
- Xamarin Test Cloud

I hope it will be helpful and meet your testing requirements [ I have used BrowserStack, Saucelabs, and AWS Device Farm]

Comment: thanks. I checked out Firebase test lab, it does not have a manual (aka Live) testing option so won't work for us. Sauce Labs may work for us, will try that